# reg: error in dataguard setup core dump eception

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

Getting below error in dataguard  is setup, any suggestion how to resolve it.

getting below error , We used with duplicate and without duplicate command but error is same. ORA-07445: exception encountered core dump [gslusslStrlen()+60] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x62882AC] [SI_KERNEL(general_protection)] []

Comment: which version exactly of Oracle 19c ?

Comment: 19.11.0  oracle version using

Comment: the error happens in the primary or in the standby ?

Comment: on standby side we use duplicate also, and without duplicate also.

Comment: This error is an internal error. If you have an Oracle support account, look at it. There is a look-up tool for ORA-600 and ORA-07445 errors. I can't publish the possible solution even if I wanted to.

Comment: could you share, what we need to check to fix this issue.

Comment: I can't do that. It is proprietary information.

Comment: I went through the documentation it's asking for diagnostic trace and  we need to raise the SR   ticket for this .